# Excel Formula for STDEV in Subtotal on specific criteria

Tags: excel

I am in need of a formula that will help me calculate the Standard Deviation of Ages for a Filtered population on my spreadsheet for the two different genders.

I have written VBA scripting that will sort the necessary values and then do the calculation, but would rather have to have the formula do the calculation so that I wouldn't have to resort to another Macro on my workbook.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccWgm.png)

What my ultimate goal is I have calculations presenting the Count, Mean and Standard Deviations for the entire population for each metric, but I am running into an issue when attempting to find the Standard Deviation on 'Filtered' data.

Comment: Hey Bryan, as written this question is hard to action. Consider adding some data and what you have tried (code/etc.) so that we have something to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like aggregate can help for that.

For Ex:

```
=AGGREGATE(8,1,A2:A11)
```

Edit: Sorry guys for this answer quickly, I thought something like that, this can be dynamic with pivot and slicer, sorry again.

[image]

Comment: I know you can't comment directly on the question yet, we've all been there. However, you just have to ask/give meaningful answers in the meantime

Comment: Personally I would use `7` for the second criterion to avoid errors also, but that is personal preference.

Comment: Good stuff :) nice to see you turned it around